# App is randomly failing to flag emails 'read' with IMAP, Javamail, Exchange 2010

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap, exchange-server-2010

I'm using Javamail with an implementation of `MessageCountListener` to read incoming emails on an Exchange 2010 server, using IMAP over an SSL connection.

We are currently testing the app.

Most days, the app processes the incoming emails and extracts their attachment files and then marks the emails as 'read':

```
try {
    email.setFlag(Flag.ANSWERED, true);
    email.setFlag(Flag.SEEN, true);
} catch (final MessagingException e) {
    log.warn("Can't set msg to read - fail transaction...", ex);
    // etc
}
```

But on some days, this doesn't work. I can see in the Outlook inbox folder that approximately 30% of the emails are left 'unread'. However there is no exception logged and the app otherwise works perfectly, so it seems.

This of course leads to problems since the app will re-process the emails and their file attachments when it is re-started, since it sees them as unread.

This is only on our test server and I haven't been able to reproduce it on my local dev box.

Can anyone advise how to approach this problem or say if they have seen it too?

My `MessageCountListener` implementation:

```
@Override
public void messagesAdded(final MessageCountEvent event) {
    Message[] newEmails = event.getMessages();
    if (newEmails != null) {
        log.debug(String.format("%d message(s) added", newEmails.length));
        for (Message email : newEmails) {
            Folder folder = email.getFolder();
            Store store = folder.getStore();
            statusOK = processor.runTransaction(email);
            if (statusOK) {
                messageCount++;
            } else {
                log.trace("shutting down listener due to error");
                store.removeConnectionListener((ConnectionListener) this);
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        log.debug("Added null new emails array");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend tracking UIDs rather than read state as to whether you've processed a message before.  That's what they're for!

Comment: Is the Folder open read/write?  Are you using Exchange 2010 on your test server?  Are any other applications (or other instances of your application) accessing the same mailbox?  You can enable [JavaMail Session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and the debug output will show you what commands are being sent to the server.  If the STORE command to set the flag is being sent, but the server isn't updating the flag, then something is wrong with the server.  If the command isn't being sent, then something is probably wrong with your application.

Comment: Yes, the Folder is open read/write, and it's using Exchange 2010 everywhere, and there are no other apps using the mailbox. I shall run it with session debug on to check the commands issued.

Comment: 2500 emails later and the issue hasn't recurred. That was in the testing environment - fingers crossed the issue doesn't kick in again when it goes into production at the weekend. If time had allowed I would have implemented @Max 's idea with the UIDs, but that had to wait.